# Convert signature from P1363 to ASN.1/DER format using Crypto++?

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++, der

I have a signature created this way:

```cxx
size_t siglenth = _signer.MaxSignatureLength();
QByteArray signature(siglenth, 0x00);
signature.reserve(siglenth);
siglenth = _signer.SignMessage(_prng,
        (const CryptoPP::byte*) (message.constData()),
        message.length(), (CryptoPP::byte*) signature.data());
```

My signature have a size of 64 and contains:

> ECCD530E5F232B7C566CA5322F990B3D55ED91156DF3845C4B9105BFE57606DDD68F332A0A5BF7CAB673E4970D10109B72F114571E7474F93ED7C89CD1B89AD4

From what I have read in `dsa.h` file this signature is currently in `DSA_P1363` format. I need to convert it to `DSA_DER` format.

To perform this action I try :

```cxx
QByteArray derSign(70, 0xFF);
size_t converted_size = CryptoPP::DSAConvertSignatureFormat(
        (CryptoPP::byte*) (derSign.data()), sizeof(derSign.data()), CryptoPP::DSA_DER,
        (CryptoPP::byte*) (signature.data()), sizeof(signature.data()), CryptoPP::DSA_P1363);
```

The output of this conversion is shown below. It seems to be only the first part of the signature. It has a size of 8 and contains:

> 300D020500ECCD53

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see [DSAConvertSignatureFormat](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/DSAConvertSignatureFormat) on the Crypto++ wiki. It is a relatively new page. It was written after this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The output of this convertion is curious, it seems to be only the
>   first part of the signature. It have a size of 8 and contains :
>
> ```
> 300D020500ECCD53
> ```
>
> What is wrong ?

Instead of:

> ```
> size_t converted_size = DSAConvertSignatureFormat(
>     (byte*) (derSign.data()), sizeof(derSign.data()), DSA_DER,
>     (byte*) (signature.data()), sizeof(signature.data()), DSA_P1363);
> ```

You should use something like:

```
size_t converted_size = DSAConvertSignatureFormat(
    (byte*) (derSign.data()), derSign.size(), DSA_DER,
    (const byte*) (signature.data()), signature.size(), DSA_P1363);
```

`sizeof(derSign.data())` yields the `sizeof` a `size_t`, which is different then the size of the string data.

Also, since `derSign` is being written to, you need a non-const pointer. The way to get that with nearly all versions of C++ is using the address of the first element:

```
size_t converted_size = DSAConvertSignatureFormat(
    (byte*) (&derSign[0]), derSign.size(), DSA_DER,
    (const byte*) (signature.data()), signature.size(), DSA_P1363);
```

Nearly finally, this is what you have in P1363, where `r` and `s` are a concatenation and each is based on the size of a field element and subgroup order:

```
[ r ] [ s ]
```

This is what you need in ASN.1/DER. There are 3 ASN.1 objects - one sequence and two integers. Each object needs one octet for the ASN.1 type, and at most two octets for the length. `r` and `s` are the size of the field element. Each ASN.1 integer may need a leading 0, so add two additional bytes for both `r` and `s`.

```
SEQUENCE = {
    INTEGER r;
    INTEGER s;
}
```

So, for the ASN.1/DER buffer, you need 3+3+3+COUNTOF(r)+1+COUNTOF(s)+1.

Finally, the snippet may look like:

```
using namespace CryptoPP;
// ... Other gyrations

std::string derSign, signature;
// ...Calculate signature

// Make room for the ASN.1/DER encoding
derSign.resize(3+3+3+2+signature.size())

size_t converted_size = DSAConvertSignatureFormat(
    (byte*) (&derSign[0]), derSign.size(), DSA_DER,
    (const byte*) (signature.data()), signature.size(), DSA_P1363);

ASSERT(converted_size <= derSign.size());
derSign.resize(converted_size);
```

---

Crypto++ now has a page on the wiki at [`DSAConvertSignatureFormat`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/DSAConvertSignatureFormat). There is an example of using `DSAConvertSignatureFormat` at [ECDSA | OpenSSL and Java](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#OpenSSL_and_Java), but the conversion is going the other way.

(Your question and lack of documentation effectively triggered a bug, and we closed the gap).

---

I just noticed this...

> ```
> size_t siglenth = _signer.SignatureLength();
> QByteArray signature(siglenth, 0x00);
> signature.reserve(siglenth);
> siglenth = _signer.SignMessage(_prng, (const CryptoPP::byte*) (message.constData()),
>                                message.length(), (CryptoPP::byte*) signature.data());
> ```

Instead use this:

```
QByteArray signature;
size_t siglenth = _signer.SignatureLength();

signature.resize(siglenth);
siglenth = _signer.SignMessage(_prng,
             (const byte*) (message.constData()), message.length(),
             (byte*) (&signature[0]));
signature.resize(siglenth);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete and efficient reply, you definitely saved my week ! :)